# CipherTrace patents

Tags: privacy, protocol

Where can we read these patents?

- "Techniques and Probabilistic Methods for Tracing Monero"
- "Systems and Methods for Investigating Monero

From
https://ciphertrace.com/ciphertrace-files-two-monero-cryptocurrency-tracing-patents/

Comment: I don't think the patents have been granted, it only seemed to have been filed. So you wont be able to read it until it's granted

Comment: Cheers, let's wait then.

Answer (score 2):

The patent application is not yet published. This is normal as it can take 1 to 2 year before publication, and more before the patent will be granted.

For example,  CipherTrace has filed the patent application US20200351278A9 titled "Cryptocurrency Based Malware and Ransomware Detection Systems and Methods" the 15th Nov 2019 but the document wasn't published until 28 May 2020. https://analytics.patsnap.com/patent-view/abst?isRedirect=1&source_type=discovery&patentId=0d6e35c6-b638-4e57-8f2b-354204f56e74

Comment: Thank you, let's wait then. From media I heard they can de-anomyse group of users but not individuals.